# Is there a way to display an instance of BezelUI (brightness HUD, volume HUD) using BASH or AppleScript?

Tags: display, applescript, bash, notifications

Long story short, I've written a simple BASH script to control the brightness of a non-Apple external monitor using [`ddcctl`](https://github.com/kfix/ddcctl). It works, with a couple hacks.

It would be **really** cool if I could display a notification when the script is called, so the end user can be aware what the current setting is relative to min/max. I just found out about AppleScript's [`display notification` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24605807), which is cool—but the notifications don't go away on their own. I also found [this essay on BezelServices](https://robert.sesek.com/2016/3/bezelservices_on_os_x.html), which is also neat—but I'm trying to do simple scripting, not creating an entire application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has created a solution to this problem: [OSDisplay](https://github.com/zulu-entertainment/OSDisplay) on GitHub.