# Where are the brightness/volume icons for BezelUI stored in Sierra / High Sierra?

Tags: display, macos, high-sierra, sound-volume, auto-brightness

As the title states. I'm using [OSDisplay](https://github.com/zulu-entertainment/OSDisplay) (as a sort of answer to my question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245882/is-there-a-way-to-display-an-instance-of-bezelui-brightness-hud-volume-hud-us/321096#321096)). I've noticed that in Sierra (or so it seems), the OS's icon for the brightness HUD changed some—longer and thinner rays, thinner inner circle, etc. I would like to change the file that OSDisplay uses so that it matches the default icon.

Apparently in the past these images were stored as PDF files in `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/BelzelUI/HiDPI`, but I do not see them there any more. The `Contents/Resources/` folder just contains a bunch of .lproj folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked on Reddit, was directed to the new location: `/System/Library/CoreServices/OSDUIHelper.app/Contents/Resources`.